# Let python read files with "open with" function in file manager (Python)

Tags: python, file

Before I begin, I'm terribly sorry if this question is a duplicate, which I think it is. But I've been researching for a solution but I can't find any answers. That's why I'm posting this.

Hi people!

In windows file manager, there's a "open with" function like this.

[Something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBUFl.png)

I'm making a music player in python and I though it will be cool to be able to open a music file and it can play with with the app.

My question is: How to open a file with the "open with" function and have the python program read it. I think I have no idea how to get the program to read the file and the Internet didn't have answers(very unusual). Any ideas on which direction I need to go to make a program that can perform such an action. Thank you!

Cheers,
CCDY

Answer (score -1):

In python you can use `open` function, which AFAIU does exactly what you want. The construction

```
with open('file.txt') as f: data = f.readlines()
```

will download all the data from file into the variable `data`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I think his question is more related to using the context menu to select the file as argument for his player.